# How Can I find sat/vb of a given Txid using bitcoin-cli

Tags: transaction-fees, bitcoin-cli, mempool, getrawtransaction

I want to find the sat/vb of a tx in a mempool. I am using bitcoin-cli to do this.

`cmd = ['bitcoin-cli', 'getrawtransaction', txid, "true"]`

This is the command that I extrect the info of the given tx but it only returns the size not the fee. Thus I cannot calculate the sat/vb how can I find how much fee is paid?

Answer (score 1):

Since Bitcoin Core v25.0 (implemented in [#23319](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/23319)) you can get the transaction fee (and prevouts) in `getrawtransaction` by setting the last parameter to `2`.